# Why is everything in bold with use the following xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I only want the date to be in bold, but somehow the whole list is in bold.
How do I change this?

```
   <ul> <xsl:for-each select="object">
             <xsl:sort select="emuIRN"/>

          <li>
              <xsl:value-of select="emuIRN"/>
              <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 

                  <b>
                      <xsl:value-of select="date_made"/> 
                  </b>


              <xsl:for-each select="materials">
                  <xsl:value-of select="material"/> 
                  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
              </xsl:for-each>

          </li>               

   </xsl:for-each>

   </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us your XML, and the HTML that's actually being output please?

Comment: Agree with Olly Hodgson that you should post your input XML.  Also, the `select="materials"` looks suspect; might you have meant `select="materials/material"` and then do `xsl:value-of` of `"."` rather than `"material"`?   Perhaps it's not that everything is bold but that somethings expected to be output are not being output at all?

Answer (score -2):

This may help you

**XML**

```
<tagname>
   <date>Make Me Bold</date>
   <date>Make Me Bold</date>
</tagname>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/tagname">
    <strong>
        <xsl:text>Here is bold text - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="date">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,startindex,endindex)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </strong>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here you have to add startindex and endindex value

Comment: Why not answer by taking the example of the OP?

Comment: @binaryBaBa Because 1. OP has not given XML 2. Given example is very much identical to explained situation